# i have problem when i install or update Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, updates

hi guys when i rty to install or update my ubuntu syste, i get this message  :

command and message :

```
mrrobot@mrrobot-pc:~$ sudo apt-get -f install upstart

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 teamviewer:i386 : Depends: qtdeclarative5-controls-plugin:i386 (>= 5.2) but it is not installable or
                            qml-module-qtquick-controls:i386 (>= 5.2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: qtdeclarative5-quicklayouts-plugin:i386 (>= 5.2) but it is not installable or
                            qml-module-qtquick-layouts:i386 (>= 5.2) but it is not going to be installed
 upstart : Depends: mountall
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
sudo apt install -f
```

Do not add `upstart` to the end.

You should not be trying to install `upstart` in the first place because `systemd` is the preferred system of booting and monitoring your system.

What you probably intend to do is:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

But as the error message states run `sudo apt install -f` all by itself first.

Comment: You're welcome. As you are new can I remind you to click the grey box next to the answer to indicate it solves the problem? Thank you.